# Accessing data in different folders in a working directory in r

Tags: r, directory

So I set my working directory, a folder called "Ril_1".

```
    setwd("~/Dropbox/Ril_1/")
```

Within this folder "Ril_1", there are two .R script files, another folder named "Score" and another folder named "Setup". In both "Score" and "Setup" folders, there are 21 .txt files that I would like to output as a list of 21 data frames, each .txt file being a data frame.

In order to do that, I've been setting the working directory three different times...

```
    setwd("~/Dropbox/Ril_1/")
    setwd("~/Dropbox/Ril_1/Score")
    #read in .txt files from "Score" file
    setwd("~/Dropbox/Ril_1/Setup") 
    #now read in .txt files from "Setup" file
```

Is there a way I can set the working directory to "Ril_1" folder then be able to read in data that's in "Score" and "Setup" folders (outputting each as a list of 21 data frames) as well as the two .R script files?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to set the directory each time? Why not just read in whatever is in your "Score" folder by adding that before the file name?

Comment: Also, look into `list.files` with the `recursive = TRUE` argument to help you get all the files in swiftly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just prepend the sub-directory to the file name.

```
setwd("~/Dropbox/Ril_1/")

# Find the filenames in the two subdirectories
score.files <- dir("Score/", pattern="txt")
setup.files <- dir("Setup/", pattern="txt")

# Go through the score files and put them in a list 
scores <- sapply(score.files, function(f)
      {
      res <- read.table(paste0("Score/", f))
      res
      }, simplify=F)

# Go through the setup files and do the same
setup <- sapply(setup.files, function(f)
      {
      res <- read.table(paste0("Setup/", f))
      res
      }, simplify=F)
```

Now you can access the content of each file using the `[[]]` operator, such as:

```
scores[[3]]
```

Comment: +1. Pretty much along the lines of what I was thinking--except I generally use `lapply` in these cases :-)

Comment: I copied the code into R and ran it.. but I keep getting this error and I don't know what I did wrong. It says:

          Error in dir("Score/", filter = "txt") : 
          unused argument(s) (filter = "txt")

Comment: @hj14: my bad, it's `pattern`, not `filter`. By the way, if you get an error/are not sure about the syntax of an R command, precede it with a question mark to get help (e.g.: `?dir`)